# How to get selected value from dropdown in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

**HTML**

```
<v-select
  v-model="selectedBank"
  :items="items"
  item-text="bankName"
  label="Select a bank"
  persistent-hint
  return-object
  single-line
>
</v-select>

<v-btn 
  round 
  block 
  color="blue darken-3" 
  dark 
  large 
  @click="directToBank(items.bankName)"
>
  CONTINUE
</v-btn>
```

**JS**

```
async directToBank(bankID) {
  console.log("Came into directtobank", this.selectedBank.bankName)
}
```

How can I get the selected value of `v-select` upon clicking on the button ?
.                                                                              .

Comment: Get the value of `selectedBank`

Comment: Cannot read property 'selectedBank' of null @kgbph

Comment: Change `this.selectedBank.bankName` to `x.selectedBank` where `x` is your Vue object declaration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are refering to [vuetify](/questions/tagged/vuetify) you can continue reading.

Let's take this example ([codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wEBRVb?&editors=101)):

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      {value: '1', bankName: 'Bank1'},
      {value: '2', bankName: 'Bank2'},
    ],
    selectedBank: null
  }),
  methods: {
    directToBank() {
      console.log("Label: ", this.selectedBank.bankName)
      console.log("Value: ", this.selectedBank.value)        
    }
  }
})
```

If you use other key for value in your items object you need to specify the **item-value** attribute in your **v-selec**t element, else it will use the "**value**" key by default.

[More on v-select component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#api)

Comment: Be careful; v-select must have **return-object** prop as above!

Answer (score 3):

When you use `return-object`, you are bringing `selectedBank` into data() hence you will only need to call `this.selectedBank.something` inside your your `@click function` in the button.

Comment: This is great <v-select v-model="selected" item-text="name" :items="tokens" item-value="" return-object></v-select>

Answer (score 1):

Getting values from vuetify select is similar to getting the values for an even fired in javascript.

**passing the even as a prop and the prop is the value you want**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    items: ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Fizz', 'Buzz'],
  },
  methods: {
    select_value(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<v-select :items="items" label="Solo field" @change="select_value" solo></v-select>
```